# Can't write to file in a loop containing sleep()

Tags: c++, file, fstream

The essence of my problem is that I can't write to a file in a loop with sleep(). If I have the following code:

```
ofstream file
file.open("file.name");

for(;;) {
    file << "HELLO\n";
}
```

This code works perfectly and prints HELLO repeatedly into "file.name". However, I want to do something like this (I'm recording data from a real-time application):

```
for(;;) {
    file << "HELLO\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

This doesn't seem to print anything into my file. Any ideas?

Comment: How can the 'C' tag be removed?

Comment: @Roddy - I tried that, didn't see how.... (oops, nevermind --- )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to flush the output.  The output stream is buffering your data into memory but not writing it out to disk.  You should either use `std::endl` (which prints a newline and flushes) instead of the string literal `'\n'`, or explicitly flush the stream with `std::flush`:

```
for(;;) {
    file << "HELLO" << endl;
}
// or
for(;;) {
    file << "HELLO\n" << flush;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! In the mean time I made a quick fix by repeatedly opening and closing the file handle in each iteration of the loop, which must have accomplished the flush.

Answer (score 3):

The magic word you are looking for is "flush".

[c++ std::ofstream flush() but not close()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341177/c-stdofstream-flush-but-not-close)

before the sleep, flush the file so that it isn't pending in a buffer waiting for there to be enough of a change to bother writing out.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just a buffering issue. Because you are now writing much slower, the output buffer wont fill up so fast so you may not 'see' the written data. Try adding a [flush()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/flush/) before the sleep.

```
file.flush()
```